# Bitbucket web-hook to run checkstyle

Tags: bitbucket, webhooks, checkstyle

Does any body know how to use bitbucket web hook to run check-style pre-push? I want to reject pushes that failed to pass check-style .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Adapt a webhook listener](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/tutorial-create-and-trigger-a-webhook-747606432.html) by cloning [atlassianlabs/webhook-listener](https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/webhook-listener) (note: uses Python wrapper for Mac OS 10.8 Notification Center: `pync`), or any listener (in any language) able to interpret the json payload of the **[webhook you declare in your repo](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2015/06/24/the-new-bitbucket-webhooks/)**.

In your case, it would be [a push event payload](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/event-payloads-740262817.html#EventPayloads-Push).

On that server, pull the latest commits to a local repo, and [trigger a checkstyle analysis](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html).

Comment: And how to reject?Seems like bitbucket does not provide such a capability

Comment: @Neil Your webhook listener could reset the remote branch to the commit parent, in effect rejecting the commit.

Comment: Might be a option. But in real life, if someone pulls while the check-style is running, and the pulled commits are rejected, that will mess up the repo

Comment: @Neil that would work if that repo is just there as an intermediate repo: if the checks pass, it would push to the actual target repo (from which devs pull, but never push). Dev can force push to that intermediate repo.